# problem in scheduler code

Tags: .net, scheduler

The following code -scheduler.vb- simulate a Windows Service Using ASP.NET to Run Scheduled Jobs. More info here: http://beckelman.net/post/2008/09/20/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-Using-ASPNET-to-Run-Scheduled-Jobs.aspx

Howerver when I try to run the class in my global.asax i get the following error (highlighted on RunScheduledTasks): "Expression does not produce a value", why?? Thanks.

global.asax

```
 Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Scheduler.Run("test", 1, RunScheduledTasks)
End Sub


 Public Sub RunScheduledTasks()
 'Do stuff here
 end Sub
```

scheduler.vb

```
 Public Class Scheduler
Private Class CacheItem
    Public Name As String
    Public Callback As Callback
    Public Cache As Cache
    Public LastRun As DateTime
End Class

Public Delegate Sub Callback()

Private Shared _numberOfMinutes As Integer = 1

Public Shared Sub Run(ByVal name As String, ByVal minutes As Integer, ByVal callbackMethod As Callback)
    _numberOfMinutes = minutes

    Dim cache As New CacheItem()
    cache.Name = name
    cache.Callback = callbackMethod
    cache.Cache = HttpRuntime.Cache
    cache.LastRun = DateTime.Now
    AddCacheObject(cache)
End Sub

Private Shared Sub AddCacheObject(ByVal cache_1 As CacheItem)
    If cache_1.Cache(cache_1.Name) Is Nothing Then
        cache_1.Cache.Add(cache_1.Name, cache_1, Nothing, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(_numberOfMinutes), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, _
         AddressOf CacheCallback)
    End If
End Sub

Private Shared Sub CacheCallback(ByVal key As String, ByVal value As Object, ByVal reason As CacheItemRemovedReason)
    Dim obj_cache As CacheItem = DirectCast(value, CacheItem)
    If obj_cache.LastRun < DateTime.Now Then
        If obj_cache.Callback IsNot Nothing Then
            obj_cache.Callback.Invoke()
        End If
        obj_cache.LastRun = DateTime.Now
    End If
    AddCacheObject(obj_cache)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Any comments will be appreciated!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You say it is highlighted on `RunScheduledTasks`.  What exactly is highlighted?  `Public Sub RunScheduledTasks()`?

Comment: If the error is in `RunScheduledTasks` why did you give us the code for everything but `RunScheduledTasks`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the link you provided, it looks like this may be an incorrect conversion from C# to VB.  The C# code automatically creates a `Callback` delegate with `RunScheduledTasks` as its target to pass to `Scheduler.Run`.

I suspect that your VB.Net code is looking at this line:

```
Scheduler.Run("test", 1, RunScheduledTasks)
```

and expects RunScheduledTasks to be a function returning a `Callback` delegate.  Unfortunately, I don't know VB.Net, so I'm guessing here.  Maybe it would work if you added the `AddressOf` operator ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74wy9422%28VS.90%29.aspx)), like so:

```
Scheduler.Run("test", 1, AddressOf RunScheduledTasks)
```

Comment: Thanks very much. The error is gone. Sorry for the basic question but I was not familiar with delegates. Thanks again.